# Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height. in listview

Tags: flutter

i have this error in flutter when using this code:
body:Container(

```
  child :Column(
    children:<Widget>[
      buildListViews1(),
    ]),),); }
```

Widget buildListViews1() {

return buildHorizontalListView1();

```
  }
```

// Horizontal List View Builder method

Widget buildHorizontalListView1() {

```
return ListView.separated(

  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),

  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,

  separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(

    color: Colors.black,

  ),
  itemCount: items.length,

  itemBuilder: (context, index) {

    return Container(

      width: 50,

      height: 50,

      child: ListTile(

        title: Text(items[index]),

      ),
    );
  },
);}
```

}

Comment: So what's the error?

Answer (score 0):

Flutter does not know what size your `ListView` should have. Try adding `shrinkWrap: true` to the `ListView`.